# How to solve Failed to run “xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet” command: notebook.tex:373:?

Tags: xetex, windows, python, convert

I am trying to convert my jupyterlab into pdf but I am getting this error server.

> nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output: Failed
> to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command: notebook.tex:373:

and here is the code that I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{documentation}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = x^2
\end{equation}
\end{documentation}
```

I want to precise that I have downloaded all the updates in MikTeX, and the same code without \document... & \begin... & \end... works fine. I also tried to change the location of \end by placing it at the end of the fist block, and it's still giving me the same error.

*PS: nbconvert Convert Notebooks to other formats.*
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please never post images of code, noone is going to want to write this off from the image in order to test the code. Please also explain what `nbconvert` is?

Comment: daleif the post is edited!

Comment: How do you call `nbconvert` and what is the content of you `.ipynb`?

Comment: First I just tried this little simple code in one cell of my jupyter-lab. So my code is only composed of this. when i try only the equation part it does work, but does'nt with \documentclass{article} \begin{documentation} \end{documentation}

Comment: Well, firstly, it should be `document` not `documentation` and secondly, you are not supposed to write a whole latex document in jupyter convert an existing notebook to latex. If you have a complete latex document, just run latex (i.e. pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex) on it.

Comment: Thanks DG for the try. I removed the \documentclass{article}, and kept only begin and end document (and not documentation) but still got the same error. Well this is, as you can imagine only a little example of what i want to do in jupyter-lab. I want to get the same result as I did when using Rmarkdown and then converting it to pdf, but with python this time. So converting a jupyter-lab to pdf seemed to me the best way to dot it. However, as you can see, even simple latex doesn't work as expected.